# I want to create digital form pdf or pdf form using node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to create a digital form pdf or pdf form using Node.js,

I want to create a pdf form which will contain dynamic question from school. Students will be able to fill their ans and upload back to school portal.

For this I want to create pdf form on my server i.e node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html-pdf. You just write some html code, in your case the form and conver into pdf template.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf